# How do I find the partition functions for the Saha equation for elements that are complex like Argon?

Tags: plasma-physics, partition-function

The question I have is with regards to the partition function needed for solving the [Saha equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saha_ionization_equation) for Argon. Basically the part I'm confused with is the part of the formula where $g_i/g_a$, where $g_i$ is the ionized partition function and $g_a$ is the atom in a "normal" or non-ionized state.

For $g_i$, I would assume I could just use the possible states when Argon has 1 or 2 electrons missing and not every electron down to the core of the atom?

This is the part that confuses me with $g_a$ is that normally the probability is something like $g_a = 2$ for Hydrogen in the ground state but what about Argon, it has 18 protons and electrons, so do I find all the possible arrangements for $g_a$?

Answer (score -1):

I'll send you to [this link](http://www.phy.ohiou.edu/~mboett/astro401_fall12/saha.pdf), in which the Saha equation is explained much better then in the wikipedia article.
As for where to find the values for the partition function, you should calculate them from the level energies and the actual temperature of your plasma. On the [NIST atomic spectra database](http://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/levels_form.html) you can find a list with most of the known energy levels (with the associated degeneracy) for every element.

Comment: Hi Beregorn and welcome to Physics.SE! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.